# How to bind multiple topics in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

After reading [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-2-apache-kafka-spring-cloud-stream) I was able to read from one topic1 and post to another topic2. But when want to read from topic2 to topic3 I get an error like "A component required a bean named 'topic3' that could not be found. So I assume I have not yet understood how the topic are bound.

That works (only for learning purposes):

```
/**
     * get sample data from topic, create objects and send them
     * @param s
     * @return
     */
    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Object processStg1(String s) {
        String arr[] = s.split(";");
        if (arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Contract")) {
            Contract c = new Contract();
            c.setId(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
            c.setName(arr[2]);
            return c;
        }
        else if (arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Cashflow")) {
            Cashflow cf = new Cashflow();
            cf.setContractId(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
            cf.setDate(arr[2]);
            cf.setAmount(Float.parseFloat(arr[3]));
            return cf;
        }

        return ("ERROR: could not parse type");
    }
```

I understand that I bound the topic via application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=topic2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.useNativeEncoding=true

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=topic1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.useNativeDecoding=true
```

Now, I would like to read Contracts from topic2 in the same application.
Something like

// that doesnt work

```
    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    public void processStg2(Contract c) {
       System.out.println("a contract was found");
    }
```

or

// that doesn't work

```
@StreamListener
public void process(@Input("topic2") KStream<String, Contract> contracts) {
    System.out.println("Found contracts");
}

public interface ContractSink extends Sink {
    @Input("topic2")
    KStream<?, ?> inputStream();
}
```

A component required a bean named 'topic2' that could not be found.

Comment: if your application is already bound to a destination using a `StreamListener`, you cannot reuse that same binding on another `StreamListener` in the same app. For instance, you cannot use `Processor.INPUT` twice on two listener methods in the same app. Can you share your repo on Github? I can take a quick look.

Comment: But how would I process data from multiple topics then and how can I build a chain of topics like (topic1 > topic2 > topic3). I uploaded it here: https://github.com/toki79/kafkatraining/blob/master/src/main/java/tki/bigdata/steams/StreamsApplication.java

Comment: Maybe I found out my self. There is a MultiInputSink. I will test that one in the evening.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found this sample, which anwered all my questions:

https://github.com/toki79/kafkatraining/blob/master/src/main/java/tki/bigdata/steams/StreamsApplication.java

Comment: I think you didn't paste the right link here. Any chance you provide the good one?